# Runtime exception in Initializing SQLiteOpenHelper constructor

Tags: android

I have used a constructor for SQLiteOpenHelper as given below: 
(I have already implemented onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods)

```
public class DB_todos extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     DB_todos(Context context){
          super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
  }
     ..........
}
```

The Runtime exception is:
Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lapp/quicklook/DB_todos;

I am confused if the way i have used the constructor is legitimate. Please give your inputs to resolve this.

Comment: Make sure you're not passing a null `Context` to the `DB_todos` constructor.

Comment: Are the values of the other arguments that you are passing up to SQLiteOpenHelper not null?

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly open the db  before accessing it ? You should open the db [ds.open() at the start of OnCreate() and ds.close() at the end og OnCreate()]